# Circle ci 2. sentry-cli can't find find dist folder to upload source maps

Tags: docker, sentry, circleci-2.0

I have a Reactjs web project where I use web pack. When I do a prod build a dist folder is created with source map in it. Then every time I create a new tag I create a new release in Sentry. But circle can't find the dist folder inside the docker image which means circle build fails.

```
  - run:
      name: Install sentry-cli
      command: curl -sL https://sentry.io/get-cli/ | bash

  - run:
      name: Create new sentry release from latest tag
      command: sentry-cli releases -o my-org -p my-project new ${CIRCLE_TAG/v/}

  - run:
      name: Upload Source Maps to sentry
      command: sentry-cli releases -o my-org -p my-project files ${CIRCLE_TAG/v/} upload-sourcemaps ./dist
```

I run this after a new tag has been pushed to docker but I get this error.

```
error: ./dist: IO error for operation on ./dist: No such file or directory (os error 2)
Exited with code 1
```

how can I make can access my dist folder with source maps in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unsure of how your project is setup - but usually the `dist` folder is in the `.gitignore` and not uploaded to GIT and as such isn't available in the CI.

If you build the app on the CI then the `dist` folder will become available. I've assumed your build command is `npm run build` but it could also be `yarn build` or any custom command you use to build your application.

```
- run:
    name: Build react application
    command: npm run build

- run:
    name: Install sentry-cli
    command: curl -sL https://sentry.io/get-cli/ | bash

- run:
    name: Create new sentry release from latest tag
    command: sentry-cli releases -o my-org -p my-project new ${CIRCLE_TAG/v/}

- run:
    name: Upload Source Maps to sentry
    command: sentry-cli releases -o my-org -p my-project files ${CIRCLE_TAG/v/} upload-sourcemaps ./dist
```